How to use a custom embeddings model with weaviate?
I have a usecase in which my entire RAG system would have to be hosted locally.
I would be running a local weaviate server along with my own huggingface embeddings model. Weaviate's documentation is a weird labyrinth understandable by only those that have either worked with weaviate for over a couple of years or their developers themselves.
Here is what I want to do:

Create an embeddings model with sentence-transformers library

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sentence_transformers.util import cos_sim
#since this embeddings model runs some custom code, we need to pass in a sentence transfomrer client with permission to trust the remote code.
embeddings = SentenceTransformer('Alibaba-NLP/gte-large-en-v1.5', trust_remote_code=True)


Use the above model to embed the documents and ingest them in the local weavite server running at 8080
Use the same embeddings model to encode some query ("This is a test query")
Retrieve from weaviate db the relevant documents that are similar to the query

The most basic most canonical usecase for a vector db. However, much to my surprise, I cannot find weaviate documentation to do this. I am stuck with weaviate for the time being. Can you help me set up this use case?

Duda from Weaviate here.
Sorry if you did not have a good experience with our docs.
We have a quick start guide for this scenario:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/starter-guides/custom-vectors
What you are trying to do is what we call "Bring your Own Vectors". Instead of letting Weaviate vectorize your objects, you provide the vectors yourself.
This is where in our docs you can check it out in multiple programming languages:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/create#create-an-object-with-a-specified-vector
You can simply provide the vector parameter with your own vectors while inserting or updating an object.
For instance, here is a python client code using the v4 syntax:
jeopardy = client.collections.get("JeopardyQuestion")
uuid = jeopardy.data.insert(
    properties={
        "question": "This vector DB is OSS and supports automatic property type inference on import",
        "answer": "Weaviate",
    },
    vector=[0.12345] * 1536
)

this will ingest data using your own vectors, by providing the vectors yourself.
Now, in order to query your data, you will need to provide a vector for that query and use the near_vector search:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/search/similarity#search-with-a-vector
Note that you can also do a hybrid search, and along with a text query, that will be used in keyword search, you also pass the vector of your query:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/search/hybrid#specify-a-search-vector
for instance, this is a code in python v4 client:
query_vector = [-0.02] * 1536  # Some vector that is compatible with object vectors

jeopardy = client.collections.get("JeopardyQuestion")
response = jeopardy.query.hybrid(
    query="food",
    query_properties=["question^2", "answer"],
    vector=query_vector,
    limit=3,
)

for o in response.objects:
    print(o.properties)

Let me know if this help!
Thanks!

would it be possible to configure a client for the same? I am trying to use dspy weaviate with a custom huggingface model and dspy consumes a weaviate client

This works for your example. However, for my usecase, I cant skip the default vectorizer mentioned in the yml that I used to spin up a local weaviate server. I am sending in the vectors of shape 1024. However, I have "semitechnologies/transformers-inference:sentence-transformers-multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1" image in the yml the stored vectors are of dimensions 384. Verified with jeopardy.query.fetch_object_by_id. Asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78503685/cant-use-my-own-vectors-in-bring-your-own-vectors-in-weaviate-it-defaults-to-se

This example fails if I modify the vector in your insert command with  list(np.array([0.12345] * 1536, dtype = np.float32)). Funnily it works if I keep the datatype to np.float64.. That is: list(np.array([0.12345] * 1536, dtype = np.float64)) works

Hey Duda, I am working on a RAG for our developers that handles a combination of natural language and code. I'm using CodeT5, so I am also rolling my own custom encoder. Initially, my idea was to setup two different encoding servers and then specify which encoder corresponds to which collection in the definition. However, I had a terrible time getting the custom encoder running.
If I'm understanding you, what we need to do in these cases is just totally bypass Weaviate's vectorization methods, and write our own handler function to create our own vectors. Is this correct?

hi Aaron, that's right. You can provide the vectors yourself directly to Weaviate.
