Cant use my own vectors in bring your own vectors in weaviate. It defaults to sentence transformer specified in the yml used to create local server
My local client creation yml
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.0
    restart: on-failure:0
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 20
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: "./data"
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: text2vec-transformers
      ENABLE_MODULES: text2vec-transformers
      TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: http://t2v-transformers:8080
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  t2v-transformers:
    image: semitechnologies/transformers-inference:sentence-transformers-multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1
    environment:
      ENABLE_CUDA: 0

I create a collection:
client.collections.create(name = "legal_sections", 
                          properties = [wvc.config.Property(name = "content",
                                                           description = "The actual section chunk that the answer is to be extracted from",
                                                           data_type = wvc.config.DataType.TEXT,
                                                           index_searchable = True,
                                                           index_filterable = True,
                                                           skip_vectorization = True,
                                                           vectorize_property_name = False)])

I create the data to be uploaded and then I upload it:
upserts = []
for content, vector in zip(docs, embeddings.encode(docs)):
    upserts.append(wvc.data.DataObject(
        properties = {
            'content':content
        },
        vector = vector
    ))

client.collections.get("Legal_sections").data.insert_many(upserts)

My custom vectors are of length 1024
upserts[0].vector.shape
output:
(1024,)

I get a random uuid:
coll = client.collections.get("legal_sections")

for i in coll.iterator():
    print(i.uuid)
    break
output:
386be699-71de-4bad-9022-31173b9df8d2

I check the length of the vector that this object at this uuid has been stored with
coll.query.fetch_object_by_id('386be699-71de-4bad-9022-31173b9df8d2', include_vector=True).vector['default'].__len__()
output:
384

This should be 1024. What am I doing wrong?

Hi there! Do you know the type returned by embeddings.encode(docs)? Do you also have a source for this library so that we can look into it and add support for its outputs.
As it stands, the client attempts to parse vectors from different data science libraries, e.g. np, tf, torch, pd, pl, but it could be that the output of embeddings.encode is not parsed appropriately. Cheers!

I am using a huggingface embeddings model. Specifically 'Alibaba-NLP/gte-large-en-v1.5'. It returns the embeddings as numpy arrays (np.float32 arrays specifically). The error seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python .. Currently, I am converting the embeddings to np.float64 to solve this

If what you say is true then the client should be passing a np.array[np.float32] without problem. Can you link the docs related to the embeddings.encode() method that you are using to be sure? In addition, which Python client version are you using?

@tsmith023 I have updated the answer to include the steps to replicate the issue. It does not require any specific embeddings module from huggingface

This is most probably a bug with weaviate (someone from weaviate can confirm). The embeddings output of the embeddings model has each element of dtype np.float32.
This leads to 2 issues:

collections.data.insert raises error that it cannot json serialize float32
collections.data.insert_many simply suppresses this bug and simply encodes using the model given in the yml used to create the client

The above code works just fine if I convert the embeddings using
vector = [float(i) for i in vector]

That is to say:
upserts = []
for content, vector in zip(docs, embeddings.encode(docs)):
    upserts.append(wvc.data.DataObject(
        properties = {
            'content':content
        },
        vector = vector
    ))

gets converted to
upserts = []
for content, vector in zip(docs, embeddings.encode(docs)):
    upserts.append(wvc.data.DataObject(
        properties = {
            'content':content
        },
        vector = [float(i) for i in vector]
    ))

code to replicate the issue with np.float32
The following code works if you don't pass the vector through the np.array with explicitly specifying the np.float32 dtype
import weaviate
import numpy as np
client = weaviate.connect_to_local()

jeopardy = client.collections.get("JeopardyQuestion")
uuid = jeopardy.data.insert(
    properties={
        "question": "This vector DB is OSS and supports automatic property type inference on import",
        "answer": "Weaviate",
    },
    vector = list(np.array([0.12345] * 1536, dtype = np.float32))
)


Ah okay! Given that you're doing list(np.array([...]), the custom parsing logic does not kick-in since the the type you're providing to vector= is list[np.float32]. If you remove the wrapping list(...) then it should work. Can you try this and verify if it does?

I had tested that doesnt work as well. The function breaks if the vector is a numpy array. WeaviateInvalidInputError: Invalid input provided: Argument 'vector' must be one of: [typing.Sequence, None, typing.Mapping], but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. I am running weaviate client '4.6.2'

Ahh, thanks for posting the exact error message! I can see what the problem is now and I will push a quick 4.6.3 patch that remedies the problem. Thanks for raising it :)

My pleasure. There is a github issue I raised with this. Maybe you can close that? https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/4978

There is a nice Weaviate Academy Course for BYOV, which might come in handy, and one of the examples even shows how to do it with HuggingFace).
Here is a docker compose configuration, which should suit better your needs - in case you want to use the hugging-face vectorization at a later stage (but it is not enabled by default):
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.1
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'none'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-huggingface'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
volumes:
  weaviate_data:
...

In your collection configuration, you don't specify a vectorizer. If you plan to do all vectorization yourself, then it is best to set it as none, like this (see the example in the docs):
import weaviate.classes as wvc
client.collections.create(
    name = "legal_sections",

    vectorizer_config=wvc.config.Configure.Vectorizer.none(),
    
    properties = [wvc.config.Property(
        name = "content",
        description = "The actual section chunk that the answer is to be extracted from",
        data_type = wvc.config.DataType.TEXT,
        index_searchable = True,
        index_filterable = True,
        skip_vectorization = True,
        vectorize_property_name = False)
    ]
)

Btw. you don't really need to specify property definition to bring in your own vectors. Also, skip_vectorization will not be used if you always provide your own vectors.
As a bonus, I would recommend configuring the HuggingFace vectorizer.
If you provide vectros with your insert calls, then Weaviate will use the provided vectors by you. Which is what you probably need at this point.
However, if later you get more data, you can send it to Weaviate without the vectors, and the vectorizer will use HuggingFace to generate the vector embeddings for you.
You can configure a collection with a vectorizer (see docs), like this:
from weaviate.classes.config import Configure, Property, DataType
client.collections.create(
    name = "legal_sections",

    vectorizer_config=[
        Configure.NamedVectors.text2vec_huggingface(
            name="title_vector",
            source_properties=["content"], # the list of properties that should be used for vectorization - if no vector is provided
            model="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", # your HF model
        )
    ],

    properties = [
        Property(name = "content", data_type = DataType.TEXT)
    ]
)

I hope this helps.
